# Should a comma appear inside the quotations in these instances?

Tags: commas, abbreviations, quotations

Here are the sentences:

"You have to get up before 8:00 a.m." John said.

"We talked about everything--books, cars, girls, movies, etc." John said.

The question is whether a comma should be used when you have an abbreviation that ends in a period at the end of the quotation.  I honestly don't know in these cases, despite looking for answers on the internet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I couldn't leave out a comma OR leave a period comma combo. So reword. AM is the form I use formally for morning hours, not a.m. And the 'everything' sentence needs no etc.

Comment: It is considered correct to put a comma after direct speech and before 'he said' or equivalent. I (UK) would put the comma outside the quotation marks, but US usage may differ.

Comment: There is the option (at least for many in the UK) of leaving full stops off many abbreviations, so the double punctuation problem is neatly pre-empted. Very few in the US seem to consider double punctuation acceptable. // Modern minimalist punctuation even relaxes the once inviolate laws of initial and terminal punctuation around quotes, internal dialogue etc. But I'd retain the comma in say "You have to get up before 8 am," John said. // Do people add '· 00' and use 'etc' in conversation?